# How to place an image between horizontal list items

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having trouble coming up with a solution here. I have a menu with a bar between list elements. However rather than a standard border, there is a break at the top and bottom.

The only solution I came up with is to use `li:after` in the CSS to place an image but for some reason the padding and margin gets all messed up. So far I have the CSS and HTML embedded below (I'm using Bootstrap as the framework here).

Any ideas on how to get these bars working?

Screenshot:

(Ignore the red color ... things were messed up in illustrator).

[image: vertical bar between elements]

```css
      #reviews .review-actions {
        text-align: center;
        z-index: 2;
        padding-top: 1px;
      }
      #reviews nav {
        display:inline-block;
        margin:0 auto;
      }
      #reviews nav ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      #reviews nav ul li{
        display: inline;
        margin: 0;
        float: left;
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: #fff;
        font-size:1.2em;
      }
      /*#reviews nav ul li:after{
        content: url('./img/menu-splitter.png');
      }*/
      #reviews nav ul > li:first-child {
        border-top-left-radius: .5em;
        border-bottom-left-radius: .5em;
        border: 1px solid #ccd0d0;
        border-right: none;
      }
      #reviews nav ul > li:nth-child(2){
        border: 1px solid #ccd0d0;
        border-right: none;
        border-left: none;
      }
      #reviews nav ul > li:last-child {
        border-top-right-radius: .5em;
        border-bottom-right-radius: .5em;
        border: 1px solid #ccd0d0;
        border-left: none;
      }
      #reviews nav ul li a{
    
      }
```

```html
    <section id='reviews'>
        <!-- Navigation -->
        <div class="review-actions">
          <nav>
            <ul>
              <li><a href='#'>The App</a></li>
              <li><a href='#'>Our Service</a></li>
              <li><a href='#'>Surprises</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set it directly in the background of the li

```css
#reviews .review-actions {
        text-align: center;
        z-index: 2;
        padding-top: 1px;
      }
      #reviews nav {
        display:inline-block;
        margin:0 auto;
      }
      #reviews nav ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      #reviews nav ul li{
        display: inline;
        margin: 0;
        float: left;
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: #fff;
        font-size:1.2em;
      }
      /*#reviews nav ul li:after{
        content: url('./img/menu-splitter.png');
      }*/
      #reviews nav ul > li:first-child {
        border-top-left-radius: .5em;
        border-bottom-left-radius: .5em;
        border: 1px solid #ccd0d0;
        border-right: none;
      }
      #reviews nav ul > li:nth-child(2){
        border: 1px solid #ccd0d0;
        border-right: none;
        border-left: none;
      }
      #reviews nav ul > li:last-child {
        border-top-right-radius: .5em;
        border-bottom-right-radius: .5em;
        border: 1px solid #ccd0d0;
        border-left: none;
      }
      #reviews nav ul li a{
    
      }
      li:nth-last-child(n+2) {
           background-image: linear-gradient(blue, blue);
           background-size: 2px 90%;
           background-repeat: no-repeat;
           background-position: right center;
      }
```

```html
<section id='reviews'>
        <!-- Navigation -->
        <div class="review-actions">
          <nav>
            <ul>
              <li><a href='#'>The App</a></li>
              <li><a href='#'>Our Service</a></li>
              <li><a href='#'>Surprises</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to deploy 4 single-pixel-width `box-shadows` around the `<ul>` as a *faux border*, and then give the `<ul>` an actual border the same color as the `<li>` `background-color`:

```css
      #reviews .review-actions {
        text-align: center;
        z-index: 2;
        padding-top: 1px;
      }

      #reviews nav {
        display:inline-block;
        margin:0 auto;
      }

      #reviews nav ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        border: 6px solid #ffffff;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px #ccd0d0, -1px 1px #ccd0d0, -1px -1px #ccd0d0, 1px -1px #ccd0d0;
        border-radius: .5em;
      }

      #reviews nav ul li{
        display: inline;
        margin: 0;
        float: left;
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: #fff;
        font-size:1.2em;
        border-left: 1px solid #ccd0d0;
      }

      #reviews nav ul > li:first-child {
        border-left: none;
      }
```

```html
      <section id='reviews'>
        <!-- Navigation -->
        <div class="review-actions">
          <nav>
            <ul>
              <li><a href='#'>The App</a></li>
              <li><a href='#'>Our Service</a></li>
              <li><a href='#'>Surprises</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </section>
```